# Python multiprocessing Pool.imap throws ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, python-unittest

I have a very simple test fixture that instantiate and close a test class 'APMSim' in different threads, the class is not picklable, so I have to use multiprocessing Pool.imap to avoid them being transferred between processes:

```
class APMSimFixture(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
        self.sims = self.pool.imap(
            apmSimUp,
            range(numCores)
        )

    def tearDown(self):
        self.pool.map(
            simDown,
            self.sims
        )

    def test_empty(self):
        pass
```

However, when I run the empty Python unittest I encounter the following error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peng/git/datapassport/spookystuff/mav/pyspookystuff_test/mav/__init__.py", line 87, in tearDown
    self.sims
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
```

Why this could happen? Is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 1):

`multiprocessing` is re-raising an exception from your worker function/child process in the parent process, but it loses the traceback in the transfer from child to parent. Check your worker function, it's that code that's going wrong. It might help to take whatever your worker function is and change:

```
def apmSimUp(...):
    ... body ...
```

to:

```
import traceback

def apmSimUp(...):
    try:
        ... body ...
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise
```

This explicitly prints the full, original exception traceback (then lets it propagate normally), so you can see what the real problem is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But this also means multiprocessing is a ill-devised library. A good library won't hide error information

Comment: Also, Since this block is used so many times, I would like to make it a function annotation, but doing so forfeit the picklability of the function, is there a way to make it succinct and show error information at the same time?

Comment: @tribbloid: It's non-trivial to forward full stack information from child to parent, but I think in Py3 it may actually fix it; use 7 year old Python, you get more quirks. You could cheat a bit on the annotation bit, and just pass the function as an argument to the wrapper; `map(mywrapper, zip(itertools.repeat(realfunc), origarguments))`, where `mywrapper` just has a body of the `try` block containing `realfunc, arg = args`, `realfunc(arg)`.